# What is the best way to concatenate two BSTRs?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

I have tried a few different way to concatenate two BSTRs and haven't haven't found  a gopd way of doing. I haven't found anything on the web at all.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a wrapper like ATL [CComBSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cd12w875%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) that also handles resource management for you.

Without a wrapper you have do:

```
BSTR Concat(BSTR a, BSTR b)
{
    auto lengthA = SysStringLen(a);
    auto lengthB = SysStringLen(b);

    auto result = SysAllocStringLen(NULL, lengthA + lengthB);

    memcpy(result, a, lengthA * sizeof(OLECHAR));
    memcpy(result + lengthA, b, lengthB * sizeof(OLECHAR));

    result[lengthA + lengthB] = 0;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    auto a = SysAllocString(L"AAA");
    auto b = SysAllocString(L"BBB");
    auto c = Concat(a, b);
    std::wcout << a << " + " << b << " = " << c << "\n";

    SysFreeString(a);
    SysFreeString(b);
    SysFreeString(c);
}
```

Comment: Wow is that really the simplest way to concat  2 strings. I'm used to C# where it would just be aString + bString; There is no existing methods that do this? Wow!!! C++ sucks

Comment: @user565660 `BSTR` sucks.  `BSTR` is a C based interface.  Wrappers that give you value-like strings exist, but are not `BSTR`s.

Comment: @user565660: Say "C++ sucks" again and it comes and shoots you in the foot. Yeap, in *Pulp Fiction* movie manner.

Comment: @hansmaad What's the reason for setting the last position of the array to 0 (result[lengthA + lengthB] = 0;)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `_bstr_t` wrapper:

```
#include <comutil.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "comsupp.lib")

// you have two BSTR's ...
BSTR pOne = SysAllocString(L"This is a ");
BSTR pTwo = SysAllocString(L"long string");

// you can wrap with _bstr_t
_bstr_t pWrapOne = pOne;
_bstr_t pWrapTwo = pTwo;

// then just concatenate like this
_bstr_t pConcat =  pWrapOne + pWrapTwo;
```

Comment: pOne and pTwo are NOT BSTR. You MUST use the SysAllocX functions to get true BSTRs (they have a 4 bytes length "prefix", sort of)

Comment: @manuell I stand corrected! Many thanks, I have amended my answer. The previous version indeed compiles ok but doesn't work, just [as it says here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069(v=vs.85).aspx).